# Sometimes we say time adverbial clause without any preposition or conjunction like:

Tags: adverbial-phrases

Sometimes we say time adverbial clause without any preposition or conjunction like:

> The last time I went to a coffee shop, I ordered a cup of americano.
>
> The first time I went to a club, I was very surprised how noisy and dark it was.
>
> The moment we laid eyes on each other, we fell in love.

Then, how about these?

I saw a girl studying at a coffee shop really hard. And about 2 weeks after I'd seen her studying at the coffee shop, I saw her dancing at a bar a week ago.

> 1. The night I saw her dancing,
> 2. The moment I saw her dancing,

I was attracted to her.

Comment: What is your question exactly? Whether they are correct? They're grammatical, though it would be more idiomatic to say: ***from** the moment..., i was attracted to her.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, those are correct. However, they may not mean exactly what you want them to.

> The night I saw her dancing, I was attracted to her.

Means that you were attracted to her that night, but not necessarily before *or since*. You probably want to indicate ongoing action, as in

> As soon as I saw her dancing that night, I was attracted to her.

or

> Ever since the night I saw her dancing, I **have been** attracted to her.

However, and this is going to be confusing, your second example is fine.

> The **moment** I saw her dancing, I was attracted to her.

That implies ongoing attraction. I think it's because a "night" is a unit of time with a clear ending, and a "moment" is not, but I honestly could not tell you exactly what the difference is. But to be safe, you could also modify that sentence with "from the moment" or "ever since the moment" to emphasize the ongoing nature of the attraction.